# react-router - no component rendered on hash change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-router

I am using Rails with react gem and react-router.js inside assets. I am using webpack in order to use require

I have my routes inside app.js:

```
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var Link = require('react-router').Link;
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var browserHistory = require('react-router').browserHistory;

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Welcome}>
            <Route path="hello" component={Hello}/>
            <Route path="welcome" component={Welcome}/>
            <Route path="about" component={About}/>
            <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

other.es6.jsx:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Hello component</h3>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Welcome = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Welcome component</h3>
                <a href="#hello">Hello</a>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var About = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>About component</h3>
                <a href="#welcome">Welcome</a>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var NoMatch = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <h3>No Match</h3>
        );
    }
});
```

When I visit *controller_name/index* it renders by default the **'Welcome component'** text with link to **'#hello'** but when clicking, it does not do anything. It's still saying **'welcome component'**

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `#` signs from you urls (or replace them by `/`) ? Here is the documentation (understanding the difference between `browserHistory` and `hashHistory` could help) https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering only welcome content not any child component. I hope this will fix it.

```
var Welcome = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
       if(this.props.children){
            return this.props.children
        }else{
          return (
             <div>
                <h3>Welcome component</h3>
                <a href="#hello">Hello</a>
             </div>
           );
       }
    }
});
```